# Add timezone offset retroactivly to SQL Server datetime entries

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc

We have our time saved without a timezone offset inside our SQL Server database. The time is actually Central Europe Standard Time but due to no timezone offset in the time string it is treated as UTC. This now creates a bunch of problems regarding daylight saving times.

My question would be: is there a way to retroactively convert the Time with offset to the correct CEST Time.

For example my time string in my database is '2022-10-30 02:00' and should be converted to '2022-10-30 00:00+2' as well as '2022-10-30 03:00' to '2022-10-30 01:00+1'.

There is an option to convert a datetime object to another timezone with "AT TIME ZONE" but this didn't help much due to the date objects being treated as UTC in the database, but we need to convert them to the UTC+[offset] format. Also due to the daylight saving time changing timezone offsets during the year, we can't subtract the timezone offsets with a set value.

Comment: Dates are binary types, they have no format. What's the field's actual type? `datetime`? `datetime2`? `datetimeoffset`? Only `datetimeoffset` has an offset. All other types have no offset or UTC indication. They aren't UTC or anything else. Whether they're treated as having an offset of `0` (ie UTC) or +1:00 is up to your queries and application.

Comment: You'll need something (a table/dataset) that has all the dates where DST starts and ends, then you can `JOIN` to  that table and apply the appropriate timezone to it (probably with `TODATETIMEOFFSET`).

Comment: I think you will need to change the datatype you are using to datetimeoffset (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). As part of your conversion, you'll probably need to manually set the offset to the desired value--AT TIME ZONE will probably be necessary.   (I'm not sufficiently familiar with this to give a solid answer and can only point to relevant documentation, but I hope to upvote a good one when it gets posted.)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The expect results you're after don't really make sense either. You state that your times are stored in CEST/CET, but then state you want `2022-10-30 02:00` to be returned as `2022-10-30 00:00+2`. If `2022-10-30 02:00` is the local time (`CEST)` then `2022-10-30 00:00+2` is *not* the same time. You imply, with your data, that you are storing the UTC time, not the local time.

Comment: Also note that when dealing with times without an offset it is *impossible* to know what time a value between the hour the clocks change represents in UTC if it falls on the day the clocks went back. For example 2022-10-30 01:30 could be either 2022-10-30 01:30 +02:00 (2022-10-29 23:30Z)  *or* 2022-10-30 01:30 +01:00 (2022-10-30 00:30Z).

Comment: I was going to give this an answer, using SQL Server 2022's new tools, but the more I look at the sample data and the expected results the less this makes sense. `2022-10-30 03:00` CET isn't `2022-10-30 01:00 +01:00`, and i have no idea how you even get those values.

Comment: @Larnu I bet the application mixed up UTC (00:00), British summer time (which is +1:00) and local CET summer time. And tried to "fix" things by offset arithmetic, resulting in inconsistent times - neither UTC nor local. `01:00` UTC  becomes `03:00` CET if you use the summer-time offset of `+02:00`. If you confuse British Summer Time with UTC, you end up with `01:00 +01:00`. If the values were *only* UTC or *only* local (no matter the DST rules), `AT TIME ZONE` or the offset-switching functions would work. And obviously, if `datetimeoffset` was used there'd be no problem

Comment: A better scenario is that the database has the correct *local* values but the OP is confused about what these should look like. `'2022-10-30 02:00' CET` **is equivalent to** `2022-10-30 02:00 +02:00` and equal to `2022-10-30 00:00` ie UTC. In this case `AT TIME ZONE` et al work. The application code should treat any time as local CET time.